# Por que o alerta impede o HTML de ser mostrado quando a página está carregando?

Tags: javascript

Alguém me pode explicar por que o `<h1>` e o `<p>` só aparecem depois de fechar a caixa de alerta?

```
<body>
   <h1>Meu primeiro programa em JS</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores quia culpa nesciunt earum! Placeat, natus.</p>

   <script>
      window.alert('Meu primeiro programa em JS');
   </script>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

De fato o HTML do `<h1>` e `<p>` são carregados antes do `<script>`. No entanto, o `<script>` nesse caso foi executado antes do HTML ser "pintado" na página, e como o `alert` é síncrono, ele impede que os elementos apareçam até que seja fechado, impedindo também qualquer outra interação na página.

Você pode ver que se atrasarmos o `alert`, a página não fica em branco:

```js
// O mínimo tempo (1ms) já é capaz de reverter esse comportamento.
//                         ↓
setTimeout(() => alert(1), 1);
```

```html
<h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
```

Mas se o `alert` for executado imediatamente, temos o que você nos mostrou:

```js
alert(1);
```

```html
<h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
```